# Xml generatiton using java

Tags: java, xml

I want to generate xml file in this format.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"  
        folio="779" fecha="2011-12-05T18:24:42"  
        sello="..."  
        formaDePago="PAGO EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION" noCertificado="00001000000102160027" condicionesDePago="EFECTOS FISCALES AL PAGO"  
        subTotal="5123.23" total="5942.95" Moneda="USD" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv3.xsd">  
      <Emisor rfc="TIA050408342" nombre="TECNOLOGIAS DE INFORMACION AMERICA S.A. DE C.V.">  
        <DomicilioFiscal calle="Montecito" noExterior="38" noInterior="P 32-5" colonia="Napoles" localidad="Distrito Federal"  
            municipio="Distrito Federal" estado="México" pais="Mex." codigoPostal="03810" />  
      </Emisor>  
      <Addenda>  
        <ElementosClientesNormales xmlns:ext="http://www.buzone.com.mx/XSD/Sender19877/A"  
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.buzone.com.mx/XSD/Sender19877/A http://www.buzone.com.mx/XSD/Sender19877/A/Addenda.xsd">  
          <Conector>TEX9302097F3</Conector>  
          <CadenaOriginal>...about 1000 characters...</CadenaOriginal>  
      </Addenda>  
    </Comprobante>
```

As we know we ca create xml file using  SAX parser or JAXB or dom4j

but still I am not able to generate tags like Comprobante:cfdi and add elements with it like folio="774" and so on.

Also how we can create tags like `Emisor:cfdi rfc`

How can I create such xml creation using java.?
Any blog , tutorial that explains the way to create such xml file.

Thanks,
Ran

Comment: You can not create XML file using SAX. Use this tutorial.http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

Comment: Why can't you create namespaced tags and add attributes to it? Without knowing how you've failed it's more difficult to provide meaningful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create elements and attributes with `namspace`.

Here is a sample code with uses the standard java xml api

```
@Test
public void genXmlWithNamespace() throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {

    String nsURI = "http://example.com/foo";

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
    Element root = doc.createElementNS(nsURI, "foo:company");
    doc.appendChild(root);

    root.setAttributeNS(nsURI, "foo:name", "example");

    Element e = null;

    e = doc.createElementNS(nsURI, "foo:employee");
    e.setAttributeNS(nsURI, "foo:id", "1");
    e.setTextContent("John Doe");
    root.appendChild(e);

    e = doc.createElementNS(nsURI, "foo:employee");
    e.setAttributeNS(nsURI, "foo:id", "2");
    e.setTextContent("John Smith");
    root.appendChild(e);

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    Result output = new StreamResult(System.out);
    Source input = new DOMSource(doc);
    transformer.transform(input, output);
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:company xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo" foo:name="example">
    <foo:employee foo:id="1">John Doe</foo:employee>
    <foo:employee foo:id="2">John Smith</foo:employee>
</foo:company>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the xml, i see it refers to XML schema files http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv3.xsd and http://www.buzone.com.mx/XSD/Sender19877/A/Addenda.xsd. Download those schemas and use JAXB for generating the Java classes. Use JAXB for generating the xml and this should be compatible with what's expected. Else, it does not make sense for the xsd references.

If you cannot get those xsd's, then the option will be as follows.
1. Use trang library to generate xsd from the above xml (http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/).
2. Cleanup the XSD. XSD generated from trang may not be always right.
3. Generate JAXB classes from the xsd using xjc
4. Modify the JAXB classes if required to associate any namespace.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to download the version of xsd that you want from SAT page (http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd)
2. Create a directory where the java classes will be created. (ex. testing)
3. Execute the command from java jdk:
   xjc -d ./testing/ cfdv33.xsd
4. You'll get some warnings from enums, but basically you'll get java classes with jaxb annotations.
5. Create a "Comprobante" for test with the java classes generated previously
6. Do a marshal

> ```
> ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
> Comprobante comprobante = of.createComprobante();
> comprobante.set...
> ...
> DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
> docBuilderFac.setNamespaceAware(true);
> DocumentBuilder db = docBuilderFac.newDocumentBuilder();
> Document doc = db.newDocument();
> marshaller.marshal(comprobante,doc);
> ...
> ```

I have a [project](https://github.com/estepuma/cfdi33-core) that you can use like a reference and maybe improve it.